# Creating custom search on jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need help with customizing jquery datatables search. I need to make main search to work for individual columns.

In fact I have to implement [this logic](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) in my main search input. So it have search logic like these individual footer inputs.

I have this code right now but its still not working as expected.

```
var table = $('#editable-usage').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

    $('#editable-usage_filter input').on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Please help.

Comment: i didn't understand your question either you want to have one search text box for all columns or have search text box for each column...
the link you provided contains example for both cases ... 
may you provide `jsfiddle` or `plnkr` for your code

Comment: I want to have one search box (main one) that have search logic like search inputs in footer provided in link above.

Comment: Post your full html table please i don't understand what's that footer inputs for better understanding i like to see the whole table

Comment: When i say footer inputs I mean for those inputs in example link i provided, my table html is classic datatables.

Comment: as i understand, you want to have the default search box but have control at the search logic for it, if the case i think you can find a food answer here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40164/search-in-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

For applying search filter to particular fields in datatables, please have a look at this code. It is for applying search only to particular columns like 2 or 3.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var term = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();      
    if (~data[2].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) return true;
    if (~data[3].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) return true;
    return false;
})
```